# alternating between the two ends of the range

Tags: python, while-loop

the question is -
Please write a program which asks the user to type in a number. The program then prints out the positive integers between 1 and the number itself, alternating between the two ends of the range

my code-

```
num = int(input('Please type in a number:'))
index = 1
while index <= num:
    print(index)
    print(num)
    index += 1
    num -= 1
```

the program is supposed to this with user input 5-

```
Please type in a number: 5
1
5
2
4
3
```

but it instead prints out this

```
Please type in a number:5
1
5
2
4
3
3
```

it prints out an extra 3 at the end, how can i fix this?

Comment: you have 2 print statements in there, the number of lines in the output will always be even, think of a different solution, or think how you can only have 1 print on the last iteration when both `index` and `num` are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = int(input('Please type in a number:'))
index = 1
while index < (num-1):
    print(index)
    print(num)
    index += 1
    num -= 1
print(num)
if index < num:
    print(index)
```

Having index < (num - 1) prevents index and num from converging. Printing (num) after the while loop takes care of the median number (3 in the case of 5 like you mentioned). If the number is even, the median will be in between 2 numbers, and The if statement at the end allows to print the smaller of those two

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**